# DS18B20 have the same 1-wire ids in proteus

Tags: proteus, 1-wire

I'm developing a temperature monitoring system and trying to model it in Proteus 8.1 SP1.
When I try to execute rom search for multiple DS18B20 it give back just 1 ID, but if I add one DS1822 I can see two Ids so I assumed that proteus has just a fixed ID for 1-wire devices.
Is it true?
Is there any workarounds of this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Place in the schematic as many DS18B20 as you need (I use three in this example)

[image]

Right click on each device and select **Edit properties**. From that shown dialog assign a different ROM serial number to each device:

[image]

As you can see the three devices now have different IDs and can be accessed individually.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found one workaround for this problem: I added DS1822 sensor which has the same interface. It was sufficient for me. Hope, it helps someone.